# files from formdata using ajax cannot be read in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

how to open a file from formData in laravel? I tried but failed

```
$(".lecture").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", $("#upload_file")[0].files[0]);
    var data = {
        courses_id : courses_id,
        content_id : content_id,
        lecture_title : $('#lecture_title').val(),
        video_duration : $('#video_duration').val(),
        video_url : $('#video_url').val(),
        total_page: $('#total_page').val(),
        file: form,
        lectur_description : $('input[name="lectur_description"]').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"{{route('studio.courses.lectures.store')}}",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
    });
});
```

[and this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNGmL.png)

Comment: Add your form markup also

Answer (score 0):

you are using formdata as value of json, use formdata to upload file and other data instead of json:

```
$(".lecture").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", $("#upload_file")[0].files[0]);
    var data = {
        courses_id: courses_id,
        content_id: content_id,
        lecture_title: $('#lecture_title').val(),
        video_duration: $('#video_duration').val(),
        video_url: $('#video_url').val(),
        total_page: $('#total_page').val(),
        lectur_description: $('input[name="lectur_description"]').val(),
    };
    for (let key in data) {
        form.append(key, data[key]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{route('studio.courses.lectures.store')}}",
        data: form,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });
});
```